# Take photo of image to send ftp server app is crashed only redmi device in android

Tags: java, android, ftp, android-camera

Take photo of image to send FTP server application is crashed only `red mi device` in android.How to solve this issue and rectify the problem.

Comment: I faced similar problem in my app and solved it.Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Check your target API in your project.Have you updated your redmi device  to MarshallMow which has an API level 23?If so change your target API and your problem will be solved.